# Netflix Turbine does not display cluster hystrix stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix

I tried to use Netflix Turbine (1.1.5) to group hystrix (1.1.5) streams.

Turbine App configuration:

```
spring.application.name=moritoring_server
server.port=8989
```

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
   eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true

turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig=MPI_Services
   turbine.appconfig=MPI_Services

Healthy-checks App which used hystrix and need to be displayed in Turbine Dashboard:

```
spring.application.name=health_checks_service
spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.discovery.serviceId=MPI_Services
server.port=8081

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.instance.metadataMap.cluster=MPI_Services
```

I can see the cluster from Eureka as below and individual Hystrix stream from Turbine is fine,

[image: erueak]

[image: Hystrix dashboard]

However, I cannot use cluster in Turbine stream and it seems keep loading,

[image: dashboard]

[image: cluster]

Could someone please advise me how to fix the issue?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 1):

Several points to check here.

1) The application that you are monitoring is providing hystrix.stream on port 8081. Try setting eureka.instance.metadataMap.management.port to 8081 in the application so that Turbine could be able to figure out the correct port. Check [this one](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR1/#_turbine) for detials.

2) I would try avoiding mixing the upper and lower case letters in the cluster names

3) When checking out the Hystrix Dashboard for shoing Turbine stream, make sure you call the demo app so that some statistics get generated. Dashboard remains empty (loading) until first messages pass through the Hystrix command

4) Wait until the Turbine app actually discovers the application cluster (check for "Found hosts" and "Hosts up" messages in the Turbine application logs). This happens after a certain timeout interval, not immediately after application startup

Here is a config that worked for me with Spring Cloud Dalston.SR1

Demo application.yml:

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  port: 8081

hystrix:
  enabled: true
```

Demo bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: demo-service
  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        serviceId: config-service

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: ${APPLICATION_DOMAIN:localhost}
    nonSecurePort: 8090
    metadataMap:
      management.port: 8082
```

Hystrix Dashboard & Turbine bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: hystrix-service
  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        serviceId: config-service

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Hystrix Dashboard & Turbine application.yml

```
...
turbine:
  aggregator:
    clusterConfig: DEMO-SERVICE
  appConfig: demo-service
```

After all pieces of the solution are started, the Hystrix dashboard is available at

```
http://localhost:8989/hystrix
```

The Turbine stream URL to use is then

```
http://localhost:8989/turbine.stream?cluster=DEMO-SERVICE
```

The complete Hystrix Dashboard and Turbine URL of the dashboard:

```
http://localhost:8989/hystrix/monitor?stream=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8989%2Fturbine.stream%3Fcluster%3DDEMO-SERVICE
```